# What is the [random:hash:?] token?

Tags: 8, tokens

I created a marketplace with two fields: a "Store Reference" field that the store owner fills, a "SKU" field I want to be unique and generated automatically.

On Drupal Commerce I want the SKU of my products to be generated automatically and made unique.

I want a sequence of numbers and random letters, for example a single SKU of 12 characters (number and letter).

There is a hash token in "Explore Available Tokens" and "Random". What is it used for?
Can it meet my needs?
Can it generate a unique code that will never be reused?

There are several store owners who can create products at the same time; the same SKU must not be generated.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a token for generating a random string. When you look [into the implementation](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/token/tree/token.tokens.inc#n982), you can see it's the result of hashing 55 random bytes with your selected hashing algorithm (the `?` part of `random:hash:?`).

Will it meet your uniqueness needs? ***Yes.***

Since we're talking pseudo-randomness here and the fact that hashing algorithms can produce collisions, there's a *possibility* of the same string being generated but it's very unlikely (unless you have a massive number of SKUs being generated).

In the unlikely event that Commerce & the AutoSKU don't have the logic to prevent SKU collision (which should be there as its a unique attribute), you can always add more patterns in the token (e.g. UID) to lessen the collision possibility to effectively zero, for the number of SKUs needed by your store.

Comment: Thank you. I have to select what like hash to generate numbers and letters. How to choose the length. I would like to have 12 and 20 characters.

Comment: Those aren't parameters in the token. If you want more than just a unique string, you'll probably need to implement your own token that can limit the string length & and used characters.